# Laravel many to many relashionship

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5

I have `users`, `meetings` and `comments` tables and I want users to be able to post comments on users profile and meetings.

I know how to make one to many relationships for users and comments tables, but I want all comments to be saved in one table and show comments on users profile and meetings.

This is my table structure:

```
users
id
name
comment_id

meetings
id
name

comments
id
user_id
comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR The solution is to use [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) which Laravel makes really easy.

IMHO I don't think that a many-to-many relationship will do the job. It would mean that:

- a user can post multiple comments. Okay
- a comment can belong to multiple user. Weird
- a meeting can have multiple comments. Okay
- a comment can belong to multiple meetings. Weird

Plus you would likely need two `comments` tables to achieve that. For instance a `comment_user` table and a `comment_meeting`.

The kind of relationship that would fit the most your situation is the polymorphic one. The name can be scary because it comes from ancient greek. But the concept behind the name is very simple. And Laravel makes [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) very easy. You will certainly recognize your situation in the example given in the Laravel documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

While saving comment, also keep a field named `model` (or anyone you like) to identify `users profile` and `meetings`

HTH